# AVR char and C# byte differ

Tags: c#, avr-gcc

I wrote a tiny C# application that writes bytes to a COM port:

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort
{
    PortName = "COM6",
    BaudRate = 57600,
    DataBits = 8,
    Parity = Parity.None,
    StopBits = StopBits.One,
    Handshake = Handshake.None
};

serialPort.DataReceived += delegate
{
    var read = serialPort.ReadByte();
    Console.WriteLine("Recv: {0}", read);
    Trace.WriteLine(read);
};

serialPort.Open();

for (Byte i = 0; i < 250; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Send: {0}", i);
    serialPort.Write(new[] {i}, 0, 1);
    Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

Now I receive these signals with my ATMega328P and send back what I received:

```
void InitUart()
{
    // Enable receiver and transmitter
    UCSR0B |= (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);

    // Set baud rate
    UBRR0H = (UART_BAUD_PRESCALE  >> 8);
    UBRR0L = UART_BAUD_PRESCALE;

    // Set frame: 8data, 1 stop bit
    UCSR0C |= (1 << USBS0) | (1 << UCSZ00) | (1 << UCSZ01);

    // Enable all interrupts
    sei();
}

void UART_Send(char b)
{
    UDR0 = b;
    while ((UCSR0A & (1 << TXC0)) == 0) {};
}

ISR(USART_RX_vect)
{
    char b = UDR0;
    _delay_ms(125);
    UART_Send(b);
}
```

But what happens is this:

```
Send: 0
Recv: 128
Send: 1
Recv: 129
Send: 2
Recv: 130
Send: 3
Recv: 131
Send: 4
Recv: 132
Send: 5
Recv: 133
Send: 6
Recv: 134
Send: 7
Recv: 135
Send: 8
Recv: 136
Send: 9
Recv: 137
Send: 10
Recv: 138
Send: 11
Recv: 139
Send: 12
Recv: 140
Send: 13
Recv: 141
Send: 14
...
Recv: 250
Send: 123
Recv: 251
Send: 124
Recv: 252
Send: 125
Recv: 253
Send: 126
Send: 127
Send: 128
Recv: 128
Send: 129
Recv: 129
Send: 130
Recv: 130
Send: 131
Recv: 131
Send: 132
Recv: 132
Send: 133
Recv: 133
Send: 134
Recv: 134
Send: 135
Recv: 135
Send: 136
Recv: 136
Send: 137
Recv: 137
Send: 138
Recv: 138
Send: 139
Recv: 139
Send: 140
Recv: 140
```

So it goes up to 127 then it is suddenly correct.

Somehow there is a 128 difference in the byte values, but I cannot get my hand on it.

Edit: after some more testing I noticed this:

```
Send: 0 (0)
Recv: 128 (10000000)
Send: 1 (1)
Recv: 129 (10000001)
Send: 2 (10)
Recv: 130 (10000010)
Send: 3 (11)
Recv: 131 (10000011)
Send: 4 (100)
Recv: 132 (10000100)
Send: 5 (101)
Recv: 133 (10000101)
```

I appears that the complements are different from C# and AVR C.

Comment: You seem to receive nothing back for 126 and 127 too - or just an edit issue?

Comment: Are you sure, your settings are correct on both sides ? IE 8bits / parity  ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are correct, there is no reply on these values.

Comment: I found a random manual on the internet for a different device (the mega644), but on that, you had to set `USBS0` in `UCSR0C` to get 1 stop bit. If it's zero, it's looking for 2. Could it be the same for yours?

Comment: I actually just did that now, but no change unfortunately.

Comment: Well, rather than `OR`ing your desired bits into the control registers, I'd try setting each of them to explicitly known values, to rule out any other oddities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I was using the wrong speed for the serial port thus the packets would not arrive properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my project but I am new in c# (and VB), it is something about ASCI and ASCII. Your code in AVR seams fine.

**What I did (in VB):**

Dim byte_conv(10) As Byte

byte_conv(0) = Pg

...

comPort.Write(byte_conv, 0, 10)

**In your case:**

Dim byte_conv(1) As Byte

byte_conv(0) = i

comPort.Write(byte_conv, 0, 1)